# Loop scoping in Sequence diagrams UML

Tags: c#, uml, sequence-diagram

Knowing that the "item" is being created within the context of the `foreach` loop only (as in, it exists in the scope of the `foreach` loop only), how would you display that within a sequence diagram (UML) by including both the contructor and destructor of the "item" object?

```
foreach (A item in itemsList)
{   item.DoStuff(); }
```

Is the way I provided below the correct one for this? Some of the answers for similar questions didn't include the scoping part (as in, the objects were all "already existing" at the head of the diagram, unlike item being created within the loop itself)?

[image]

Comment: The item always exists before the loop because it was in the list before the loop was created. After the loop is closed those items will remain inside the list, and you can't remove them because you are using a foreach so the lifespan on each object inside the loop is longer than the item inside the loop. So your UML isn't exactly correct

Comment: @DanielLoudon So the item basically is a reference to the existing item in the list, and not a new object. Thanks.

Comment: Yes hence if you make a change to each item in your foreach loop, then the change is reflected in the list. I.e. A list of integers and you use a foreach to iterate through the list and add one to each integer, after the loop each number in the list will still have been incremented rather than the list being the same before the foreach and all changes applied to a new object and disposed off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct. `A` is not created but assigned with the pointer to the according element in the collection.

[image]

Comment: That explains it decently. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the middle element be defined as something like itemList : List<A>?

Comment: @Zenith You are right. I don't have the source anymore and are too lazy to fix it right now. I'd guess the main point is not about the `A` being generic and the an answer is still valid. Will try to fix it soon...

Comment: @Zenith made a fix...